# Cell class change is postponed till next edit or scroll

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to mark edited in [UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) cell by blue color. For this purpose in `afterCellEdit` event I make some changes in the row entity. `cellClass` function checks for these marks and returns corresponding class name. Call to `$scope.$apply` (specified in documentation) is also used.

Following example is simplified as there is no check, what column has been edited. In the real app I have more complicated code to mark specific cell. But this example is enough to show the problem:

1. Select cell in `Company` column (but not in the last row).
2. Change the value there.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   Tha value changes, `Edited` column changes to true, selection moves to the next row, but **the text in edited cell is still black**.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.
   Text in edited on step 2 cell becomes blue.

**How can I force color change on step 3 instead of 4?**

http://plnkr.co/edit/SEEf4DPhA3CB1mx7R4I8?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.cellNav']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'edited',
      enableCellEdit: false
    },{
      field: 'company',
      cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
        return row.entity.edited ? 'blue' : '';
      }
    }],
    
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
      gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
          rowEntity.edited = true;
          $scope.$apply();
        }
      });
    }
  };

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellNav class="grid"></div>
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/560552/178988)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `notifyDataChange` to let uigrid know the value has changed.

juste inject `uiGridConstants` in your controller and replace `$scope.apply()` by `gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);`

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.cellNav']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http,uiGridConstants) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,

    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'edited',
      enableCellEdit: false
    },{
      field: 'company',
      cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
        return row.entity.edited ? 'blue' : '';
      }
    }],

    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
      gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
          rowEntity.edited = true;
          gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
        }
      });
    }
};

$http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

A working plunker :
http://plnkr.co/edit/GrseKTm6EF2CdWiNhXM7?p=preview